# boost::trim_right_if and null characters

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<char> some_vec = boost::assign::list_of('1')('2')('3')('4')('5')('\0')('\0');
  std::string str(some_vec.begin(), some_vec.end());
  boost::trim_right_if(str, boost::is_any_of("\0"));
}
```

I think that in str should be "12345", but there's "12345\0\0". Why and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know this functions boost::is_any_of but the fact that its argument is a string literal it seems it considers "\0" as an empty set of characters (en empty string literal). So the algorithm trims nothing.

It is only my supposition.

Comment: Your supposition is correct.  To fix, use: `boost::is_any_of(std::string("\0",1))`

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley I think that should be boost::is_any_of(std::string('\0',1)) that is there should be ordinary quotes.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The `string` constructor has an overload that takes a `char const *` and count, so Benjamin's correct. The OP can also use a lambda expression `[](char c){return c == '\0';}` for the predicate.

Comment: No. That is a different constructor, but you have the arguments reversed. i.e. you could use `std::string(1,'\0')`

Comment: @ Benjamin Lindley After I wrote the comment I saw myself constructors of std::basic_string. And indeed the record you showed can be used.:) Now I think what constructor is better in this case And in my opinion it is better to use consreuctor with charT instead of const charT *:)

Comment: @ Praetorian, Yes, i see.

Answer (score 3):

This code works

```
boost::trim_right_if(str, boost::is_any_of(boost::as_array("\0") );
```

The trick is to use `boost::as_array`